# Customizing the Remove Button and Logging the Number of Removals

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a report button for a social media app. I want someone to be able to click the remove button for a post in a cell. Then it will remove the cell for them (but not everyone else) and increment a variable called reports which I can review in Firebase to determine if the post is inappropriate. I have already made the remove function for the following Post class:

```
import Foundation

class Post {
    var id:String
    var title: String
    var text:String
    var createdAt:Date
    var reports: Int
    func report() {
        reports+=1
    }
   init(id: String, title: String,text:String,  timestamp:Double) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.text = text
        self.createdAt = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp / 1000)
        self.reports =  0



    }
}
```

And here is my remove post function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){



    posts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

I would like that instead of the button saying "Remove" it says report. I would also like that every time someone reports a post, it increments the report variable. Eventually, I would like that all posts with a report variable higher than some integer are removed. How would I customize the remove function in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I would like that instead of the button saying "Remove" it says report.*
This can be easily done by - `yourButton.setTitle("Report", for: .normal)`

or

```
yourButton.titleLabel?.text = "Report"
```

Coming to the next part - 
Whenever someone reports, you need to call API or whatever way you are using to update the stored value of report count, then reflect this in your app by getting the newly increased value in response.

You can use `Timer` to check the value of report counter in your desired time interval, and if the value exceeds, remove the post.

Edit - As there is no use of buttons

You can change the title of that red box by these delegate methods

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
    { 
       tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true) 
    }
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? 
    { 
     let more = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Report") 
     { action, index in 
       print("Report button tapped")
     }
     more.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue 
     return [more] 
    }
```

Comment: I agree it would be easy if it were a button, but I am using a function such that when you slide a cell to the left, a red report box appears on the right. I never made any buttons. Swift does that with the code I wrote automatically. I agree with you about the second way. I am not sure how to call Firebase to update the variable programatically.

Comment: @RyanSchiller You can change the title of that red box by these delegate methods
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
      
      let more = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Report") { action, index in
            print("Report button tapped")
        }
        more.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        
        return [more]
    }